# Solr stopwords gets indexed but returns 0 results

Tags: solr, lucene

I am trying not to index stopwords for all the Textfields.

My managed-schema.xml looks like:

```
<fieldType name="text_en" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer>
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="lang/stopwords_en.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.EnglishPossessiveFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
   </analyzer>
 </fieldType>
<field name="ItemDesc" type="text_en" multiValued="false" indexed="true" stored="false"/>
```

However when I look at the solr field description it does show me the stop words in the "load term info" tab [screenshot](http://postimg.org/image/vb9t7k2pr/)

However when I click on the stopword like "on" it gives me 0 results. [screenshot](http://postimg.org/image/oomooxpap/)

So is solr indexing the stopwords or not?

I looked at the solr documentation and it says: "Clicking that button will show the top N terms that are in the **index** for that field"
which means that stopwords like "on" are indexed however when I click on the word it returns 0 results for only all the stopwords.

Comment: Is it possible that 'on' stop word is getting indexed from some other field? You indexed the data with same configuration, provided above, it is not like you indexed the data and later added the stopword filter to fieldType.

Comment: You should expand a bit your question. I'd add the field definition and the result of the query execution with queryDebug=true. It is not clear if the field you're querying is associated with that field type and if, in the field analysys, you'ree seeing that field / fieldType

Comment: Okay I have also added the field. @abhishekbafna The screenshot of all the stop words shown is just for that specific field.

Comment: @abhishekbafna I tried changing the order of the filters but it didnt work  and yes I am sure that the index terms shown in the screenshot are for that specific field..is there any config that I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally figured out the problem.
The schema file is correctly filtering out the stopwords.
The problem is the PorterstemFilterfactory which stems the keywords such as "one" to "on" and "use" to "us" and indexing them making it look like the stopwords are not filtered out.
I dont know if this is a bug in Porterstem or it is suppose to be that way.

Comment: This is normal behaviour. If you want to avoid that, you can re-use `StopFilterFactory` after your `PorterStemFilterFactory` !